# Dropwizard and Docker: yaml configuration didn't change default ports

Tags: docker, dropwizard

I'm trying to run dropwizard service using Docker.

In dropwizard, I already used yam configuration to change the default port to 8085. But when I run my dropwizard service using Docker, the service still running on default port 8080.

I tried the command:

docker run -p -d 8085:8085

It bind port 8085 on the host to port 8085 in the container, but the service still run on 8080.

Could anyone tell why the service still running on port 8080 and how to make it run on 8085.

Thank you.

BTW, if I run my dropwirzard service using eclipse, it will run on 8085 without any problems.

Comment: docker run -d -p 8085:8080 should work. Assuming that dropwizard running with default port. To map both the ports use docker run -d -p 8085:8080 -p 8086:8081  here 8081 port bind to 8086.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is you didn't actually configure dropwizard to run on the port you expected.